# How to Update COM1 port default settings(baud rate,parity) C#

Tags: c#, baud-rate

I am using Windows XP Professional edition.

As my project requirement i want to update COM1 port default settings to my customized settings.

My Computer -> Manage -> Device Manager -> Ports -> Communications Port -> Port Settings ->

default settings are,

1. Baud Rate  ===  9600
2. databits   ===  8
3. parity     ==   none
4. stop bit    ==   1

I want to change the above settings to

1. Baud Rate  ===  2400
2. databits   ===  7
3. parity     ==   even
4. stop bit    ==   2

(what ever i am changing here in code should reflect in device manger ->port settings

Thanks in  advance

Comment: What does this question have to do with C#? Do you want to change the system defaults for that port? Do you need a C# program that you run once to change the defaults? Or do you want to change the settings in a C# program to only affect that run?

Comment: I need a C# program to change the system default settings for that port.

Comment: Problem Solved .The Code is..Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey myKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Ports", true);
            myKey.SetValue("COM1:", "2400,n,7,1");

Comment: can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64203396/6854117) related to it?